# Generate SOAP Request from WSDL (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I'm looking for a way to generate a SOAP Envelop for a specific web method from a WSDL proxy class using .NET framework (c#)

I looked over the internet and did not see responses to this exact request.
I know i can call the proxy directly but i need to get the SOAP message itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Download SOAPUI and this should be able to generate SOAP messages for you if you provide it the WSDL.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I should have mentionned that i need to do this programatically :-)

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?
I'm asking because i need to do the exact same thing ...
Thanks in advance for any input

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the SOAP message so you can add certain fields to the SOAP header?  You can decorate your classes with MessageContractAttribute and then specify which fields go in the SOAP header vs the body

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

for details

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Basically question is how would i achieve the following:
- From WSDL, programatically create a SOAP Request message to call a specific web service
- Then that message may be forwarded to some client over say message queue transport. Then that client piece would take the soap message and send it to the web service.

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is the preferred means of using web services in .NET and best practice.  It automatically creates the SOAP message for you, which eliminates the need for developers to understand SOAP messages (a good thing) in most cases.  In Visual Studio you simply do Project->Add Service Reference... and give it your WSDL.  It will generate the client Stub for you which will have local methods that translate to your WSDL methods.  When you call the local methods in your client code, the Stub translates the calls to SOAP requests and sends them over your transport